# How can I label graph series using a labels derived from a matrix?

Tags: octave

I have a number of series to plot. I want to use a matrix to generate series labels or legends.

eg. if `K=[2 4 6]`, where each element of `K` corresponds to a series, I want series labels to be something like `"K=2", "K=4" and "K=6"`.

Here is my code:

```
function Y=Q(X)
    Y=0.5.*erfc(X./sqrt(2))
endfunction

EbNodB=0:2:20
EbNo=10.^(EbNodB/10)
K=[2 4 6]
M=2.^K
KM=3*K./(M-1)
KME=KM'*EbNo
X=sqrt(KME)
Pb=((4./K).*(1-1./sqrt(M)))'.*Q(X)
semilogy(EbNodB,Pb)
title("M-QAM BER")
grid on
grid minor on
#legend(sprintf("K=%d,",K))
```

This comes close - just missing `"K="` in front of each legend:

```
legend(num2str(K'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take the string returned by the sprintf and do a string split with the commas as the delimiter

```
legend(strsplit(sprintf("K=%d,",K),","))
```

The only annoyance this gives is the `warning: legend: ignoring extra labels` because you have an empty string after the last comma, but this can be fixed by not passing the last value

```
legend(strsplit(sprintf("K=%d,",K),",")(1:end-1))
```

Comment: Ta. Works fine, but I feel that Octave should have matrix string operations as well to avoid this manual processing.